# Laravel: raw query setup

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need a hand with the following.

I have a `plates` table which contains, among other things, `project_id` and `equipment_status_code_id`.

Here is what I am trying to achieve.

I would like to query the table and fetch the results just like this.

```
 ----------------------------------------------------
| project |    Equipment Status code  | Number of plates
-----------------------------------------------------
| Test    |      Cleaning             |          9 
| Test#2  |      Not Cleand           |          3
|         
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Doing something like this

```
return   DB::table('plates')
    ->select('project_id', 'equipment_status_code_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
    ->groupBy('project_id','equipment_status_code_id')
    ->pluck('project_id','equipment_status_code_id');
```

returns

```
{
  "13": 31,
  "30": 3,
  "": 3
}
```

But this is just not enough. I would like to to add another layer just like the example above with column names.

What's the best way to achieve this?

**Note**: I know that I need to query the model to fetch the names of the status codes instead of `id's`.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Join `equipment_status_code_id` with the table thats have the status names, and select the name instead of the id

Comment: @Vuldo I need total of plates as well. Do you mind showing me an example which contains projects, status code and N of plates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
return  DB::table('plates')
    ->join('project', 'plates.project_id', '=', 'project.id')
    ->join('equipment', 'plates.equipment_status_code_id', '=', 'equipment.id')
    ->select('plates.*', 'project.name', 'equipment.equipment_code', DB::raw('count(plates.id) as no_of_plates'))
    ->groupBy('plates.project_id','plates.equipment_status_code_id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try run with `DB::raw("Your SQL statement here");` In this way you can write your own statement like you write in sql.

My example in Modal:

```
  public static function getMaxOrder()
    {

        $orderno = DB::select(DB::raw('select order_no from orders where id = (select max(`id`) from orders)'));
        return $orderno[0]->order_no;
    }
```

Comment: no need to use DB::raw() when we are already using DB::select()